# External Dell Display doesn't work with MacBook Pro (2011) after Thunderbolt Firmware Update (1.0 and 1.2)

Tags: macbook-pro, external-display, thunderbolt

Today two Thunderbolt Firmware Updates (1.0 and 1.2) became available for my MacBook Pro (Early 2011). After installing both, my external monitor, a Dell U2713HM, does no longer work. The system detects the display, but the display shows only black.

An Apple Thunderbolt display works fine and a MacBook Air can use the Dell monitor without problems. My MacBook Pro can use the Dell monitor just fine when I boot from a USB stick.

Therefore, clearly the Thunderbolt Firmware Update seems to be the problem.

Does anyone have the same problem? Any solutions or workarounds? I guess there is no way to remove a Thunderbolt Firmware Update once it's installed, right?

Update 24.10.2013:

Is there no one else with this problem? In the meantime I tried three different cables – none worked. My colleague with the same generation MacBook Pro also can't use my display after installing the firmware update. All colleagues with MacBook Airs and newer MacBook Pros (all didn't receive the firmware update) can use the display.

Update 29.10.2013:

Wow, ok today my new MacBook Pro Retina 13' (Late 2013) arrived. Guess what, I cannot use the display with it. Only HDMI works – not with the full resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved itself after I moved to another room in the office. I have no idea why. On my new desk the display works again. The only explanation I can think of is that unplugging the monitor during the move reseted something.